# How do I get my array to fit into sklearn?

Tags: numpy, svm

I want to feed two np arrays to an sklearn svm. I have two groups of data

```
group1 = [[0.067, 0.21], [0.092, 0.21], 
  [0.294, 0.445], [0.227, 0.521], [0.185, 0.597], 
  [0.185, 0.689], [0.235, 0.748], [0.319, 0.773], 
  [0.387, 0.739], [0.437, 0.672], [0.496, 0.739],
  [0.571, 0.773], [0.639, 0.765], [0.765, 0.924],
  [0.807, 0.933], [0.849, 0.941]]

group2 = [[0.118, 0.143], [0.118, 0.176], 
  [0.345, 0.378], [0.395, 0.319], [0.437, 0.261],
  [0.496, 0.328], [0.546, 0.395], [0.605, 0.462],
  [0.655, 0.529], [0.697, 0.597], [0.706, 0.664],
  [0.681, 0.723], [0.849, 0.798], [0.857, 0.849],
  [0.866, 0.899]]
```

The groups are 15 and 16 elements long each. How would I go about putting this into an SVM that would give me an equation that seperates these two numbers?

I tried to impute the average of group 2 onto the end and then concatenate them into a 64 sample 1D array. But I can't get the y vector in clf.fit to work with the array I made.

What I have so  far

```
from sklearn import svm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use("ggplot")

group1 = [[0.067, 0.21], [0.092, 0.21], 
  [0.294, 0.445], [0.227, 0.521], [0.185, 0.597], 
  [0.185, 0.689], [0.235, 0.748], [0.319, 0.773], 
  [0.387, 0.739], [0.437, 0.672], [0.496, 0.739],
  [0.571, 0.773], [0.639, 0.765], [0.765, 0.924],
  [0.807, 0.933], [0.849, 0.941]]

group2 = [[0.118, 0.143], [0.118, 0.176], 
  [0.345, 0.378], [0.395, 0.319], [0.437, 0.261],
  [0.496, 0.328], [0.546, 0.395], [0.605, 0.462],
  [0.655, 0.529], [0.697, 0.597], [0.706, 0.664],
  [0.681, 0.723], [0.849, 0.798], [0.857, 0.849],
  [0.866, 0.899]]
    def print_group(group):
        for i in group:
            for j in i:
                print j


    #print_group(group1)
    len_group1=str(len(group1))
    len_group2=str(len(group2))

    #c = " ".join([a, b])
    print "length of group 1" + " " + len_group1 + " " + "units in group 1"
    print "length of group 2" + " " + len_group2 + " " + "units in group 2"

    np_1= np.array(group1)
    np_2= np.array(group2)

    mean1, std1 = np.mean(np_1), np.std(np_1)
    mean2, std2 = np.mean(np_2), np.std(np_2)
    mean2_a=np.array(mean2)

    np22=np.append(mean2_a, np_2)
    np22=np.append(mean2_a, np22)




    np1=np_1.ravel().reshape(32,1)
    np2=np22.ravel().reshape(32,1)

    #
    #print(mean1, std1)
    #print(mean2, std2)
    #


    np3=np.concatenate((np1,np2))
    #plt.scatter(np_1, np_2)
    #plt.show()
    #
    #np11=np1.reshape(1,-1)
    #np22=np2.reshape(1,-1)

    #np.append(np2,mean2)
    #np.append(np2,mean2)

    clf = svm.SVC(gamma='scale')
    classified_array= np.zeros((64, 0))
    clf.fit([np3],[classified_array])

File "<ipython-input-39-50dcfc391d51>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/AliDesktop/Desktop/Magic Briefcase/Jobs/StarMind.py', wdir='C:/Users/AliDesktop/Desktop/Magic Briefcase/Jobs')

  File "C:\Users\AliDesktop\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\AliDesktop\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 87, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "C:/Users/AliDesktop/Desktop/Magic Briefcase/Jobs/StarMind.py", line 76, in <module>
    clf.fit([np3],[classified_array])

  File "C:\Users\AliDesktop\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 151, in fit
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, dtype=np.float64, order='C', accept_sparse='csr')

  File "C:\Users\AliDesktop\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 521, in check_X_y
    ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)

  File "C:\Users\AliDesktop\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 405, in check_array
    % (array.ndim, estimator_name))

ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is properly label the data points. If you assign the variables for the clf, you'll begin to see the issue.

```
X, y = np3, classified_array
```

You will see that your data and target vectors are not correct. I would try starting the problem with these lines.

```
group_data = [i+[0] for i in group1] + [i+[1] for i in group2]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=group_data, columns=['x','y','target'])
```

This will create labels 0 for group 1 and 1 for group 2. Then you can assign your data like so,

```
X,y = df[['x','y']].values, df.target.values
```

Comment: This is confusing. I'm not sure I could come up with this solution myself.


for i in group 2:
        [i+[]1]

for [0.118, 0.143] in group 2:

Comment: This is confusing. I'm not sure I could come up with this solution myself.


[for i in group 2:
        [i+[1]] ]

[for [0.118, 0.143] in group 2:
    [0.118, 0.143] +1]

That's the logic correct?

Comment: This is a list comprehension and it makes creating lists more concise. You can read the first term of group_data as, for each element of group1 append 0. This can be done because each element of group1 is a list that can be appended. Each term of group_data is a list and so they can be appended in the same way. Which will give you the dataset you need for your SVC model.

Comment: Just to clarify I did not need to convert the data to pandas dataframe. I could have written the following X = np.array(group_data)[:,[0,1]] and y = np.array(group_data)[:,2] you will see that these are equivalent to X,y = df[['x','y']].values, df.target.values

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, group1 and group2 belong to two different classes, so we have binary classification problem. Lets solve it.

```
from sklearn import svm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

group1 = np.array([[0.067, 0.21], [0.092, 0.21], 
  [0.294, 0.445], [0.227, 0.521], [0.185, 0.597], 
  [0.185, 0.689], [0.235, 0.748], [0.319, 0.773], 
  [0.387, 0.739], [0.437, 0.672], [0.496, 0.739],
  [0.571, 0.773], [0.639, 0.765], [0.765, 0.924],
  [0.807, 0.933], [0.849, 0.941]])

group2 = np.array([[0.118, 0.143], [0.118, 0.176], 
  [0.345, 0.378], [0.395, 0.319], [0.437, 0.261],
  [0.496, 0.328], [0.546, 0.395], [0.605, 0.462],
  [0.655, 0.529], [0.697, 0.597], [0.706, 0.664],
  [0.681, 0.723], [0.849, 0.798], [0.857, 0.849],
  [0.866, 0.899]])

# Choose appropriate C
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=100)

clf.fit(X, y)

plt.plot(group1[:,0], group1[:,1], 'ro', group2[:,0], group2[:,1], 'bx')
ax = plt.gca()
xlim = ax.get_xlim()
ylim = ax.get_ylim()
xx = np.linspace(xlim[0], xlim[1], 20)
yy = np.linspace(ylim[0], ylim[1], 20)
YY, XX = np.meshgrid(yy, xx)
xy = np.vstack([XX.ravel(), YY.ravel()]).T
Z = clf.decision_function(xy).reshape(XX.shape)
ax.contour(XX, YY, Z, colors='k', levels=[-1, 0, 1], alpha=0.5,
           linestyles=['--', '-', '--'])
ax.scatter(clf.support_vectors_[:, 0], clf.support_vectors_[:, 1], s=100,
           linewidth=1, facecolors='none', edgecolors='k')
plt.show()
```

[image]